# Behaviour of C# get on a member of class inside VS2008 Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I Was explaing some module to one of my friend and i had to step into debugging mode for showing some values of some variables/Properties by setting the breakpoint.

For normal case if i set the breakpoint in side the get/set the breakpoint is hit for normal program flow and would show correct result.
What i found amusing is that VS debugger will also use the same(i.e to call the get method) to know the property value.

**As a debugger it should be able to get the state of the program without actually Disturbing it or having any side effect.**

Try the below code  set few break points and hover the mouse over the Property count at `console.write()`. You would find that count changes without actauly being hit by the breakpoint inside the `get`.
Just by hovering mouse over the property it fetches the value from it which could be a pain to understand in some weird debugging session.

I know People can say that get shouldn't modify the member or bad design, but in some cases it is best to write in get() such as to test for null and return a new object if it is null;

```
public class Test
{
    int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            _count++;
            return _count;
        }
    }
}
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test tCount = new Test();
        Console.Write(tCount.Count);
    }
}
```

**Do you feel this is the correct behaviour of VS?**,

As debugger should not modify the state of the program.
Even if it modifies the state it should step through the breakpoint.

Only reason i can think of why debugger doesn't step through the breakpoint is then it has to stop/break the debugging thread of itself to hit the breakpoint which will stop it.

Comment: I see your point but it's like a rule of physics, you cannot observe anything without affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to me to be the ideal way for it to behave.  if you want to have the tooltip show the propery value, it clearly needs to call the property.  i, for one, wouldn't want that to cause the debugger to break, though.  this is exactly what i would hope for.

Comment: Exactly, It wouldn't want to cause the debugger to break at the breakpoit itself set. That would be Paradox.

Answer (score 3):

A property getter or setter is basically the same as a method. The debugger cannot prevent side effects while evaluating it. If you don't want the side effect, then directly read the value of the field (_count in your example) with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger is just another client of your class and thus needs to execute the code of your class to present you with the value. In doing this, the debugger might change the state of your class.
However, this really shouldn't be a problem as long as you adhere to the design guideline to make getters as simple as possible. If you change a value in your getter, you most likely are violating the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: A, Yes, because debugger is just another client for my class if you take it as someone calling and using my class, But a No because debugger should not modify or change the state of the program. Even now i dont have a problem with the programa and design. My concern is why the side effcet. Okay, As you said it is another client for me then it should step through the get code and hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is the correct behaviour.  You asked it to evaluate `Count` so it did.  How was it meant to know that you REALLY wanted it to evaluate `_count` ?

Properties and fields are not always paired up one-to-one.  Properties are much more like methods than like fields.  Would you like to be able to execute methods without side effects too?

What about setter properties?  If you used the debugger to deliberately change the value of a property would really want the value to remain constant?

Answer (score 0):

Getters are quietly decorated with the [SpecialName] attribute.  This changes the goal posts somewhat, and here's a reason.  Change your code to...

```
    public class Test
    {
        int _count;
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                _count++;
                throw new Exception("hello");
                return _count;
            }
        }
    }
```

and hover over the console.writeline before it's executed.  You'll see that the debugger reports that an exception occured!  You would not have this type of reporting otherwise.  So yes, it's expected behaviour.